# Django: How to migrate to class-based indexes

Tags: django, django-models, django-migrations

Django 1.11 introduced [Class-based model indexes](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/releases/1.11/#class-based-model-indexes). What was previously defined as

```py
class A(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        index_together = [
            ('foo', 'bar'),
        ]
```

Can now be defined as

```py
class A(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        indexes = [
            models.Index(fields=['foo', 'bar']),
        ]
```

When I change to the new syntax for a model an run `python manage.py makemigrations`, it will create migrations like

```py
class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('app', '0001_initial'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.AlterIndexTogether(
            name='a',
            index_together=set([]),
        ),
        migrations.AddIndex(
            model_name='a',
            index=models.Index(fields=['foo', 'bar'], name='app_a_f12345_idx'),
        ),
    ]
```

This migration will remove and re-create my indexes, which is something I'd like to avoid.

What is the recommended way for switching from the old to the new syntax? I could not find anything in the documentation.

Comment: I don't think you're supposed to use the Index class with `index_together`. Just use `indexes` with multiple fields.

Comment: That was my mistake. It should have been indexes all along. I've fixed that in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can edit the generated migration so that the index `name` matches your original `index_together` index name, then run `manage.py migrate` with `--fake` option.

Comment: Good idea! It somehow seems strange that there is not an easier (or any documented) way for doing this. Also I will have to rename my indexes because some of the old auto-generated ones exceed the 30 char limit that the Index class imposes.

Comment: Well, I don't see why you _need_ to switch to the `indexes` syntax at all. I use the new syntax only when I need to skip the creation of an extra index for `LIKE` lookups (which is autogenerated for character fields when `db_index=True` is used with PostgreSQL backend) or when I need a `GinIndex` or `BrinIndex`.

Comment: I agree that there is not generally a need to switch. However when I do have a reason to define an index the ``indexes` way, I'd like to move all of the indexes of that class there.

Comment: It seems that there is no official / recommended way, so as this seems to be the only reasonable solution I've marked it as accepted.